# two shower faucets in one water supply line

Tags: shower, faucet

If I add a second shower faucet ( his & her) in the same shower will reduce the water pressure in both faucet,
How do I maintain the same water pressure in both faucets when they both operate the same time.
Thanks

Comment: The first thing you'll want to do, is increase the size of the pipe supplying the bathroom.  Then you'll have to build a manifold type setup to supply the faucets.

Answer (score 1):

Larger supply piping and a "parallel" (as opposed to "series") manifold arrangement will help, but you need to realize that there is only so much you can do. You are limited by your home's water supply pressure and size.

Probably the easiest thing to do is use low flow "water saving" shower heads/nozzles.

If you want to do more, check the size of your: water meter, water meter union, and main water line. Increase the size of all if possible. Also, check to see if your main water supply has a pressure regulator installed. Check your static (no-flow) pressure downstream of the regulator to determine if you can raise the regulated pressure (check your city bldg. office for max allowable pressure). Older homes with steel water piping often suffer from low gpm/lpm flow rates, consider a complete re-pipe if this is the case.